# Powershell if statement in pipeline

Tags: powershell, command-line

I am in need to create a script which can continuously read a file and if a certain line with text comes, to call a function.

I am thinking in a way to do this a single line thing with

```
Get-Content -Path $logFile -wait | ?{$_-match "$filter"}
```

but I am not aware of a way to call a function if the line does answer the criteria.

Is that doable ? or I should do it like in a loop to read the file every cycle and if there is a match to exit the loop ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pipe it to a foreach loop, which will go through each line individually, and you can put the if statement in the loop:

```
Get-Content -Path $logFile -wait | %{if($_ -match "$filter"){Callfunction}}
```

Comment: You might want to filter before the ForEach loop. `gc $logfile -wait|?{$_ -match "$filter"}|%{callfunction $_}` ...also, if his answer solved the issue please mark it as the accepted answer so he gets credit.

Comment: Yes I know :) just stackoverflow wanted me to wait for few minutes before I would be able to mark it as an answer and his way solve my problem. Thanks guys

Comment: TheMadTechnician is right, *You might* want to iterate through every line with the Where-Object cmdlet, and then pipe the lines you want to another loop. Personally, *I* would not want to, Because 1) there is no reason to and 2) Your performance will seriously suffer with large log files